# "Subscript out of range" error, and need to copy and paste title row to create pivot

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that will copy and paste rows from Sheet1 that meet a keyword criteria (Milestone) in Column E, and copy rows to a Sheet2.

The date is then extracted on Sheet2 and entered in to a new column, but I am receiving the error

> Subscript out of range (Error 9)

when this action is complete.

I cannot see what is causing this?

I also need to first copy and paste the 10th row from Sheet1 to the 1st row in Sheet2 to use as categories for a Pivot Table?

```
Sub mileStoneDateChanger()

Dim r As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long, v() As Long, i As Long

Dim lastRow As Long


Dim lCol As Long

lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row

MsgBox "Last Row: " & lastRow



pasteRowIndex = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
For r = 1 To lastRow
    If .Cells(r, "E").Value Like "Milestone*" Then
        If UBound(Split(.Cells(r, "E"), ",")) > 0 Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim v(1 To i)
            v(i) = pasteRowIndex
        End If
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(r).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(pasteRowIndex)
        pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1
    End If
Next r
End With



With Sheets("Sheet2")

  newLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("B1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row

If IsArray(v) Then
    .Columns(6).Insert shift:=xlToRight
     For i = 1 To newLastRow
        .Cells(i, "F").Value = Split(.Cells(i, "E"), ",")(1)
    Next i
End If


End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the out-of-range error, because you assume that you have a comma in `Cells(i,"E")` here:

```
For i = 1 To newLastRow
    .Cells(i, "F").Value = Split(.Cells(i, "E"), ",")(1)
Next i
```

With the code above, you take the second value of an array, coming from the splitted `Cells(i,"E")`, by a comma. This, if the value in the cell is `123,45`, you would take `45`. Most probably, there is a case, where you do not have any comma, thus there is no second value. So, you have to make a check. E.g. something like this:

```
If InStr(1, .Cells(i, "F"), ",") Then
    .Cells(i, "F").Value = Split(.Cells(i, "E"), ",")(1)
End If
```

Comment: thanks for the solution! Do you also know how I can take only the tenth row from sheet1 to sheet2 in order to create a pivot with the headers? Thanks

Comment: @SDROB - you are welcome. Concerning your question, try to record a macro, and examine the code. Then change it a bit, it should work.

Comment: If I replace the line    .Cells(i, "F").Value = Split(.Cells(i, "E"), ",")(1)        from the original code with the solution you mentioned, the dates do not split in to the new column as needed. Any thoughts?

Comment: @SDROB - you are splitting dates by comma?

Comment: It works, I changed      InStr(1, .Cells(i, "F"), ",") Then       to       InStr(1, .Cells(i, "E"), ",") Then